# Erro em código OCTAVE

Tags: matlab

Acabei de iniciar em programação no OCTAVE e meu código apresentou o seguinte erro:

[image: Código da função]

Comandos e chamada da função

```
>> A = imread('cameraman.tif');
>> B = imread('circuit.tif');
>> D = sub_img(A,B);
```

Erro:

> warning: suggest parenthesis around assignment used as truth value
>   near line 4, column 15 in file 
>   'C:\Users\rafae\Octave\0-intro-matlab-octave\sub_img.m'
>
> error: in computed assignment A(index) OP= X, A must be defined first
>
> error: called from
>       sub_img at line 4 column 3

Com isso, tentei outras fontes de pesquisa para achar a solução, porém nenhuma me serviu. Agradeço a atenção

Answer (score 1):

Bom após a ajuda do ederwander. Pude chegar a outras soluções e consegue deixar o código "correto" a principio.

Após a correção feita o código imprimia o que era para ser imprimido 'images are not the same size'. Porém outro erro apareceu error: value on right hand side of assignment is undefined. Para corrigilo foi necessário colocar um valor para a variável C (C = 0) a função C = sub_img(A,B). Com isso o código da função ficou:

[image: Código alterado]

Então, após utiliza-lo ele emitiu a mensagem, porém percebi que o código nunca sairia do if pois a condição <= sempre seria verdadeira, com isso deixei apenas <. E para o 'else' funcionar, eu fiz um script que altera o tamanho da imagem B para ficar igual ao tamanho da imagem A e assim mostrar a imagem com os pixels substraidos.

Script (Vale ressaltar que o script possui uma tarefa diferente da função, eu só aproveitei mesmo o comando resize):

clear;  %Limpa as variaveis

A = imread('cameraman.tif'); % Lê a primeira imagem

B = imread('circuit.tif');  % Lê a segunda imagem

imshow(A); pause(3);  %Mostra a primeira imagem e espera 3 segundos
imshow(B); pause(3);  %Mostra a segunda imagem e espera 3 segundos

B = imresize(B, size(A)); %Altera o tamanho da imagem B para o tamanho da imagem A

C = imadd(A,B); imshow(C); %Mostra a somatoria 8 Bits

[image: Duas imagens com seus pixels subtraidos]

Bom, a principio meu problema foi solucionado, e gostaria de pedir que caso alguém tenha algum livro, fonte, arquivo para indicar para estudar programação em octave eu agradeço.

Obrigado Ederwander!

Answer (score 0):

Acho que tem um erro de sintaxe na sua função, não existe ou eu pelo menos nunca vi  esse tipo de operador em octave/matlab `-=` eu acho que vc quer comparar se as dimensões de A e B são iguais então vc deveria usar o operador `==`, o primeiro `Warning` que apareceu no seu código foi pq vc não adicionou mais parenteses em seu `if` segue um simples teste com as observações acima rodando no Octave sem erros:

```
A = [1 2 3]
B = [1 2 3]
if ((size(A) == size(B)))
    disp("oi")
end
```

Comment: Realmente, depois do que você escreveu pesquisei um pouco melhor e -= não existe, o certo seria <=. Provavelmente, como eu estou usando um livro "velho", a nomenclatura utilizada nele já não exista mais. Você por acaso teria alguma nomenclatura? Além disso, com o que você falou vou postar a resposta da solução e as alterações que eu fiz :)